# Paths for sinatra through jruby, tomcat

Tags: tomcat, sinatra, jruby

While developing a Sinatra app to run behind thin, paths are pretty easy.

Now that I'm launching via a warbled war file in tomcat, things have changed. The root is now one more level deep (`/warFileName/`) and relative addresses are relative to the route/url, so if I have two routes get 'dostuff' and get 'subdir/dostuff', sourcing any files (js, css, images) is different between the two (the first I can just do `'js/blah.js'` and it'll properly look in `public/js`, the second it will look in `subdir/js` and fail). And, I can't do a root slash anymore (`/js`), because of tomcat pushing things a level deep as I said before (`/warFileName/subdir/doStuff`).

Assuming I don't want to hardcode `/warFileName/` into all my image/js/css/etc references, and I'd rather not have my routers pass stuff on to haml like `@root = ".."` or `@root = ""` depending of if we're in a pseudo-subdirectory or not, is there an elegant way of handling this?

Comment: i'm also looking for the answer to this one, I'll post here if i figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Sinatra URL helper is the best way to handle this.

```
<%= url '/path' %>
```

or, if you want to eval some Ruby inside the URL path:

```
<%= url "/path/#{foo}" %>
```